# What would be a real-life example of using a quantum workflow oriented tool/environment, such as through Orquestra?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-algorithms, orquestra

Recently, a unified quantum software and hardware platform, [Orquestra](https://www.zapatacomputing.com/orquestra/) was released. My question is, what could be a real-life (step by step) example of using this kind of workflow? As existing quantum software frameworks already offer algorithm development toolboxes, what additional features would such a workflow include? Thanks.